# Exibir o slide só depois de carregado

Tags: jquery, bxslider

Gostaria de uma ajuda pois quando carrega a minha página, o meu slide fica todo bagunçado, e só depois de uns 5 segundos ele volta ao normal e isso acaba causando uma má impressão.

Gostaria de algo com `jquery` ou `ajax` que mostrasse meu slide só depois de carregado todo ele.

Referencia estou usando um slide `jquery bxslider`

```
 <div class="slider-area">
        <!-- Slider -->
        <div class="block-slider block-slider4">
            <ul class="" id="bxslider-home4">
                <li>
                    <img src="img/h4-slide.png" alt="Slide">
                    <div class="caption-group">
                        <h2 class="caption title">
                            iPhone <span class="primary">6 <strong>Plus</strong></span>
                        </h2>
                        <h4 class="caption subtitle">Dual SIM</h4>
                        <a class="caption button-radius" href="#"><span class="icon"></span>Shop now</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li><img src="img/h4-slide2.png" alt="Slide">
                    <div class="caption-group">
                        <h2 class="caption title">
                            by one, get one <span class="primary">50% <strong>off</strong></span>
                        </h2>
                        <h4 class="caption subtitle">school supplies & backpacks.*</h4>
                        <a class="caption button-radius" href="#"><span class="icon"></span>Shop now</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li><img src="img/h4-slide3.png" alt="Slide">
                    <div class="caption-group">
                        <h2 class="caption title">
                            Apple <span class="primary">Store <strong>Ipod</strong></span>
                        </h2>
                        <h4 class="caption subtitle">Select Item</h4>
                        <a class="caption button-radius" href="#"><span class="icon"></span>Shop now</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li><img src="img/h4-slide4.png" alt="Slide">
                    <div class="caption-group">
                      <h2 class="caption title">
                            Apple <span class="primary">Store <strong>Ipod</strong></span>
                        </h2>
                        <h4 class="caption subtitle">& Phone</h4>
                        <a class="caption button-radius" href="#"><span class="icon"></span>Shop now</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- ./Slider -->
</div> <!-- End slider area -->
```

Agradeço desde já desde já

Answer (score 0):

Execute o seu slide só quando a página terminar de carregar.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
});
```

Comment: Olá Kayo! Não sei qual o motivo mas tentei varias formas até mesmo essa sua, mas não funciona usei até o $.noConflict();

Comment: Estava vendo aqui e na verdade preciso que esse slide carregue o mais rápido possível, pois ele só funciona depois que a pagina carrega e enquanto isso ela fica toda bagunçada na tela.... =( Eu precisava que ela sumisse e mostrasse só depois de totalmente carregada

Comment: Amigo coloca ele pra ser carregado no header.